# jQuery function does not work on mouseover and click state

Tags: javascript, jquery

Building a new site and trying to reuse a JavaScript from the current site that change image on hover. I have a hard time to understand JavaScript so I hope someone can help me to see what I'm missing or doing wrong.

The current site (where I copied from) has many more script running and I don't know if some other script is missing. I have tried to change the initializing part of the script to fit the new site. Please have a look at the puzzlepiece on the current page. http://www.collyfiltreringsteknik.se.

I have got the script running to a point where it adds the four "quad" divs but the mouseover and click function does not work.

This is the html code

```
<div id="companyvalues" class="clearfix">
  <div class="valueimage"></div>
</div>
```

The jQuery part

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        companyvalues: function(kwargs) {
            var defaults = {
                static_base:''
            };
            var options = $.extend(defaults, kwargs);
            return this.each(function() {
                  var obj = $(this);
                  var div = $('div', obj);
                  var topleft = $('<div class="quad topleft" data-image="i0000" data-href="/grundpelare/tillganglighet/"></div>');
                  var topright = $('<div class="quad topright" data-image="i0003" data-href="/grundpelare/konkurrenskraft/"></div>');
                  var bottomleft = $('<div class="quad bottomleft" data-image="i0002" data-href="/grundpelare/miljoforbattring/"></div>');
                  var bottomright = $('<div class="quad bottomright" data-image="i0001" data-href="/grundpelare/kostnadsreducering/"></div>');

                  obj.prepend(bottomright);
                  obj.prepend(bottomleft);
                  obj.prepend(topright);
                  obj.prepend(topleft);

                  var divs = $('div.quad', obj);
                  $([ '/uploads/pages/varden_0000_yellow.png',
                      '/uploads/pages/varden_0001_red.png',
                      '/uploads/pages/varden_0002_green.png',
                      '/uploads/pages/varden_0003_blue.png'
                      ]).preload({base_url:options.static_base});

                  divs.mouseover(function(event) {
                      var item = $(this);
                      var data_image = item.attr('data-image');
                      div.addClass(data_image);
                      event.preventDefault();
                      event.stopPropagation();
                  });

                  divs.mouseout(function(event) {
                      var item = $(this);
                      div.removeClass('i0000');
                      div.removeClass('i0001');
                      div.removeClass('i0002');
                      div.removeClass('i0003');
                      event.preventDefault();
                      event.stopPropagation();
                  });

                  divs.click(function(event) {
                      var item = $(this);
                      var href = item.attr('data-href')
                      document.location.href=href;
                      event.preventDefault();
                      event.stopPropagation();
                  });

            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Initializing the script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#companyvalues').companyvalues();
});
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the console?

Comment: There is no errors in the console. Can also see that the "quad"-images is not loaded like they are on the current site.

Comment: I will also add that I have created a basic html-page with only this script and a jQuery link to minimize other problems.

Comment: I found it. There was a preloader missing.